# php connection to sql server

Tags: php, sql-server

I am attempting to connect to a database created in MS Studio, which I did not create.  The creator of the db asked me to create a website, which I did using PHP/HTML.  Now I need to connect the two and display his data to the page.

I'm hoping for some hand-holding here, I'm pretty new (obviously), and I am working alone on this project as the creator only uses VB.

First thing I'm trying to do is establish a connection to the db, and I'm having no luck, I just get a 500 error, which as far as I can tell is a syntax error.

I've tried this code here http://webcheatsheet.com/php/connect_mssql_database.php using the information sent by the creator, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance!

I was using this code.

```
<?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "your_name";
$myPass = "your_password";
$myDB = "examples"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT id, name, year ";
$query .= "FROM cars ";
$query .= "WHERE name='BMW'"; 

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result); 
echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>"; 

//display the results 
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<li>" . $row["id"] . $row["name"] . $row["year"] . "</li>";
}
//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: Could  you show us the code of what you've tried?

Comment: Please show your actual connection and PHP code (strip out database username/password).

Comment: 500 errors have more details in the server logs. start by looking there.

Comment: Added code to first post.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mssql_get_last_message() 

Try this to get the error message to see why you cant connect to the db server.
something like
if(!$connect) // This is your db handler
{
die('I cannot connect because:'.$mssql_get_last_message());
}
```

Comment: I think part of the problem is terminology, he's giving me: Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX which I find odd...

Comment: It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: *This is the result from adding the code you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the drivers were missing from the server (solved by the administrator of the db) aside from having the wrong db name.

Now on to building the html page.